# Logback: logging issues in resteasy java application deployed on tomcat server

Tags: java, maven, logback, resteasy, tomcat9

The logging output is not as per configurations defined in logback.xml so it seems logback.xml file is not loaded.
I saw the answers related to similar questions but nothing is helping me. Please any help would be appreciated.

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.30</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

**logback.xml**
I have placed it in src/main/resources folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xml>
<configuration scan="true">
    <!-- Send debug messages to System.out -->
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{5} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <!-- By default, the level of the root level is set to DEBUG -->
    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

**Service Class** that logs the statements to console:

```
public class HelloWorldService {
    final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HelloWorldService.class);

    public HelloWorld findById(int id) {
        logger.info("finding the message by Id");
        logger.error("error happened");
        logger.debug("in debug mode");
    }
}
```

**Current output:**

[http-nio-8080-exec-3] INFO com.mastek.service.HelloWorldService - finding the message by Id

[http-nio-8080-exec-3] ERROR com.mastek.service.HelloWorldService - error happened

**Expected output:**

Time Thread_name INFO com.mastek.service.HelloWorldService - finding the message by Id

Time Thread_name ERROR com.mastek.service.HelloWorldService - error happened

Time Thread_name DEBUG com.mastek.service.HelloWorldService - in debug mode

Comment: Is logback definitely being used as the logging implementation here?

Comment: I have added the pom.xml snippet providing the related dependencies in the question.

Comment: Can you run with `-Dlogback.debug=true` and paste any relevant output?

Comment: The problem is with logback-classic dependency. Removing the test scope from this dependency helped in printing the debug statements with timestamp. Thank you!